# Google Play Games Services iOS GIDSignIn Login Issue

Tags: ios, google-play-games, robovm

Apple rejects all apps which force user to sign-in out of the app like safari. New framework GIDSignIn has the build-in mechanism for authentication via WebView. All works perfect. 
BUT how do I login to google play game services using this GIDSignIn?

There is a method in GPGManager for signing with GPPSignIn object but unfortunately it seems there is no way to use GIDSignIn object instead.

**My question: is it possible to somehow use GIDSignIn authentication for signing in to GPGS?**

Comment: Just follow [the docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in) in how to set it up? The instructions are pretty thorough.

Comment: Hang tight! there is an update to the SDK to use GIDSignin coming soon.

Comment: Hi, Clayton Wilkinson, could you please say approximate date when SDK surely will be released?

Comment: The new SDK is out: https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/sdks